# Redirecting Cartthrob to a different gateway when cart_total = $0?

Tags: cartthrob, payment-gateway, redirection

I'm working on a digital downloads site that has free and paid downloads.

When only free items are in the cart at checkout, I want to use the ct_offline_payments gateway without cc data, but for some reason cartthrob is not loading the offline payments gateway called within the conditional, and is loading the default gateway (moneris_direct).

The transaction fails due to missing cc data.

Here is my code.

```
{if "{exp:cartthrob:cart_total}" > 0}

{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form id="gateway" secure_action="yes" gateway="moneris_direct" return="{template_group}/order_complete"}

{gateway_fields}

<fieldset class="promo" id="promo">
<p><label for="coupon_code">Enter Promo Code</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" /></p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="payment" id="payment">
<img id="payment_cards" src="/assets/images/payment_cards.jpg" width="171" height="22" alt="Visa, Mastercard, American Express, Diners Club" align="right" /><legend>Payment Info</legend>
  <p class="required">* All Fields Required</p>

    <p><label for="credit_card_number"><span class="required">*</span> Credit Card Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="credit_card_number" value="" id="credit_card_number" class="required" /></p>

    <img src="/assets/images/RapidSSL_SEAL-90x50.gif" width="90" height="50" alt="Secured with RapidSSL" align="right" />
    <p><label for="CVV2"><span class="required">*</span> Card Security Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="CVV2" value="" id="CVV2" /></p>

    <p><label for="expiration_month"><span class="required">*</span> Expiration Month</label>
    <select name="expiration_month" id="expiration_month">
        <option value="11">November</option>
    </select></p>

    <p><label for="expiration_year"><span class="required">*</span> Expiration Year</label>
    <select name="expiration_year" id="expiration_year">
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select></p>

</fieldset>

<input type="hidden" value="{clear_coupon_codes}">
<input type="submit" value="Complete Purchase">

{/exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}

{if:else}

{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form id="gateway" gateway="ct_offline_payments" return="{template_group}/order_complete"}

{gateway_fields}

<input type="hidden" value="{clear_coupon_codes}">
<input type="submit" value="Download">

{/exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}

{/if}
```

I have recently upgraded cartthrob to 2.6.1 from 2.05x, so it may be a syntax issue.

I have made sure it's not a (strict) conditionals issue with EE 2.9.x.

Any thoughts, or example working code to share?

Thanks very much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a very similar case atm. I think I have just found the solution:

Use `{if '{exp:cartthrob:cart_total prefix=""}' > 0}`

instead of: `{if "{exp:cartthrob:cart_total}" > 0}`

Check out [this reply](http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/4575/#24492) in the CT forums for further reference.